# Exception caught : java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: mysql, jdbc

```
 public void updateDeduction(String empId, String dedId, String dedname,String dedamount,String date) throws SQLException{
 //update the contributions
  stmt = conn.createStatement();
 String updateString ="INSERT INTO deductions (empId,dedId,dedName,dedAmount,dedDate) VALUES (";
  updateString +="'"+empId+"', ";
  updateString +="CURDATE(), " ;
  updateString +="'"+dedId+"'";
  updateString +="'"+dedname+"', ";
  updateString +="'"+dedamount+"')";


  stmt.executeUpdate(updateString);

  return;
```

I am getting error whenever I am clicking on the deduction tab please let me know what to do?

Comment: besides missing a comma after dedId,Why don't you insert values in the order they should be? empId->dedId->dedName->dedAmount->dedDate?You are missing dedDate.

Comment: There must be a way to do this that uses placeholders so that you're guaranteed to have things properly escaped and quoted.

Answer (score 4):

It is good practice to use `PreparedStatement` instead of `Statement`. It will help you to prevent `sql injection` attacks. Try to build `PreparedStatement` like -

```
String updateString ="INSERT INTO deductions (empId, dedId, dedName, dedAmount, dedDate) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";

    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(updateString);

    preparedStatement.setInt(1, empId);
    preparedStatement.setInt(2, dedId);
    preparedStatement.setString(3, dedName);
    preparedStatement.setDouble(4, dedAmount);
    preparedStatement.setDate(5, dedDate);

    preparedStatement .executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do this is to use [PreparedStatement](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html). I've rewritten OPs code below to show how this is done:

```
public void updateDeduction(String empId, String dedId, String dedname,String dedamount,String date) throws SQLException{
    //update the contributions
    PreparedStatement updateString = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO deductions (empId,dedId,dedName,dedAmount,dedDate) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE); // you passed in CURDATE() instead of using one of your parameters.
    updateString.setString(1, empId);
    updateString.setString(2, dedId);
    updateString.setString(3, dedName);
    updateString.setString(4, dedAmount);
    updateString.setString(5, date); // you were missing this line
    if (updateString.executeUpdate() == 1) return;
    else throw new RuntimeException("Update failed");
}
```

Some comments on my code which should make it clearer as to why I used this style. The if line exists to ensure the insert was successful, as [executeUpdate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) is defined to return the number of rows inserted in an insert context. Also, you **must** declare your statements as updatable if they change rows at all. Hope this helps, and if you need further assistance/explanation, please leave a comment here.

Comment: The addition of `, ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE` to the `prepareStatement` method is unnecessary: this query does not produce a resultset. This is only meant for ResultSets that allow you to update selected rows throught the `ResultSet`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a comma in `updateString +="'"+dedId+"'";`

Also the order of the values you concatenate into the string do not match the order of fields in the `INSERT INTO (...)`

The fix would be something like

```
  updateString +="'"+empId+"', ";
  updateString +="'"+dedId+"', "; //Or updateString += dedId+", ";  If dedId is an integer value in the database.
  updateString +="'"+dedname+"', ";
  updateString +="'"+dedamount+"', ";
  updateString +="CURDATE())" ;
```

Notice I've re-ordered the string concatenates to match the `INSERT INTO (...)` field order, and all the fields have commas after them except the last one.

Comment: Yes, and do use PreparedStatement like some of the other answerers said. I was just helping with the syntax error.  But they are going a step further by showing what is also conceptually correct, and you can see how doing this would have helped avoid the syntax error in the first place.

Comment: Exception caught : java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect integer value: 'null' for column 'dedId' at row 1

Comment: If dedId is an integer in the database, then the line should be: `updateString += dedId+", ";`

Comment: Basically, anything that is a string in the database needs to be `INSERT INTO (stringfield) VALUES('stringvalue')`.  But anything that is not a string cannot have the ' in VALUES:  `INSERT INTO (intField) VALUES(123)` is an example