# Exception caught : java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect integer value:

Tags: java, mysql, sql

**Error:**

> Exception caught : java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect integer value: '[Ljava.lang.String;@26fd19c6' for column 'dedId' at row 1 The database could not be connected

**Program**:

```
public void updateDeduction(int empId, String[] dedId, String dedName, String dedDate, String dedAmount) throws SQLException{
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    String updateString="INSERT INTO deductions (empId,dedId,dedName,dedDate,dedAmount) VALUES (";
    updateString +="'"+empId+"', ";
    updateString +="'"+dedId+"', "; 
    updateString +="'"+dedName+"', ";
    updateString +="'"+dedAmount+"', ";
    updateString +="CURDATE())" ;
    stmt.executeUpdate(updateString); 
    return;
}
```

Comment: [**Little Bobby Tables alert!**](http://xkcd.com/327/) - don't concatenate together your SQL statements - that's just **asking** for trouble....

Comment: I dont get it that why is the SQL exception showing?

Comment: Zain [check this out :)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14169162/exception-caught-java-sql-sqlexception-column-count-doesnt-match-value-count) +1 @marc_s

Comment: i tried that out but its giving me the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Parameter `dedid` is an *array* of strings. When you executed

```
updateString +="'"+dedId+"', ";
```

it was converted to the string `[Ljava.lang.String;@26fd19c6`.

You need to figure out which of the array elements you want to use.

As others have commented, building a statement by concatenating user-provided text like this is a sure way to get hacked via [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).  You should be using `PreparedStatement` instead, with placeholders, i.e.

```
INSERT INTO deductions (empId,dedId,dedName,dedDate,dedAmount) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
```

Comment: With regards to SQL injection and using `PreparedStatment`, will it automatically strip out any unsafe characters or is that still left up to the programmer?

Comment: The presence of "unsafe characters" is immaterial as the values do not get substituted into the SQL literal. They go directly into the text value and cannot modify the SQL.